# Can u guys tell me how i take things from scripts and put them all together in lua?

Tags: lua, roblox, lua-scripting-library

Can you guys tell me how I take things from scripts and put them all together in Lua for a Roblox script I am trying to make it would also be helpful if you told me how I could reverse a loadstring into the raw script so I can copy some features from the other script

Comment: Heyo, it's really unclear what you're trying to do. Could you elaborate a little more what it is you've tried, what isn't working, and any errors you are getting.

Comment: I kinda fixed the problem but can u tell me how I can make a autofarm in lua and incorporate other people's scripts into mine so like using thier loads Tring as part of a big GUI feature

Comment: Can I add me on discord I am Deleted User I've added you already so we can talk